# How to add a calculated field in a group by in access?

Tags: ms-access, group-by

I am attempting to combine two groupings(sum), EPL and POL and relabel them as something, say "Other GL". The current output is this. I've attempted adding a formula in the criteria but it is not working. I have also attempted adding another column in the design view with a formula alone. [image]

[image]

Comment: Combine how? "Not working" means what - error message, wrong results, nothing happens? Edit question to show attempted SQL statement and criteria. Show sample source data and desired output.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to "combine" data rows for grouping (i.e. sums) is to create a preliminary query which reassigns the individual source rows to a common value.  Then use that query as the source for the other query(ies).  (Such a preliminary query could be either a nested query -a.k.a. subquery-, or a saved query.  I personally prefer saved queries since they can be edited and viewed using the standard Access Query Designer, whereas subqueries can only be edited as SQL text.)

Without other database schema or SQL statement to work with, all I can show is a SQL snippet showing the altered selection:

```
SELECT iif(Claims2.Grouping = 'EPL' Or Claims2.Grouping = 'POL', 'Other GL', Claims2.Grouping) As AltGrouping, ... 
FROM Claims2
```

For what it's worth, the same `iif()` statement could also be inserted directly into the your query as a "calculated field"--within the query designer just copy and paste it into the Field cell in place of `Grouping`.  But a saved query that adjusts labels preliminary to final queries can be reused and makes later queries simpler.

Comment: This worked to relabel the two grouping above, but it results in multiple columns for each coverage. Where do I input the final sum to have one row for each?

Comment: Please edit the question and add updated query details and a sample of the data with the problem you are trying to explain.  As it is, your description seems contradictory.  Your primary question was to combine two rows and now you say that you want "one row for each"--you can't have it both ways.  I also don't understand why you are getting more columns unless your underlying data changed or the grouping intervals have changed.